# How to display Select - where condition value in input type textbox in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table Tax contains tax_id (1 & 2) ,Tax_price(12 & 8) & Tax_name (vat & Gst).

I want to display the VAT price in a textbox('txtvat')

```
SQl Query : SELECT`tax_price` FROM `tbl_taxmaster` WHERE `tax_name` = "VAT"
```

View

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col col-md-4"><label class=" form-control-label">VAT</label> 
</div>
<?php foreach($taxvat as $row){ ?>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">

        <input type="text" id="txtVat" name="txtVat" value="<?php echo $row->tax_name;?>" class="form-control">

    </div>
<?php } ?> 
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function displayBillingPage()
{   

    $this->load->model('CrudModel');        
    $records['taxvat']=$this->CrudModel->getVatName();
    $this->load->view('generatebill',$records);
}
```

Model

```
public function getVatName()
{
    $this->db->select('tax_price');
    $this->db->from('tbl_taxmaster');
    $this->db->where('tax_name',"VAT");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result()->row()->tax_price;          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `row()` and `result()` at the same time

`row()` is used to get only one row and `result()` to get more than one

If you are using `row()` then you can do this `row()->column_name`. But can't with `result()`

And if using column name in `select()` then don't do this `row()->column_name`

IF you are getting only one row no need to use `foreach` loop

**For one row**

*Method 1*

```
public function getVatName(){
     $this->db->select('tax_price');
     $this->db->from('tbl_taxmaster');
     $this->db->where('tax_name',"VAT");
     return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

*Method 2*

```
public function getVatName(){
   return $this->db->get_where('tbl_taxmaster', ['tax_name' => 'VAT'])->row()->tax_price;
}
```

**For multiple rows**

*Method 1*

```
public function getVatName(){
     $this->db->select('tax_price');
     $this->db->from('tbl_taxmaster');
     $this->db->where('tax_name',"VAT");
     return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

*Method 2*

```
public function getVatName(){
   return $this->db->get_where('tbl_taxmaster', ['tax_name' => 'VAT'])->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**view :**

```
<div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col col-md-4"><label class=" form-control-label">VAT</label></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
<input type="text" id="txtVat" name="txtVat" value="<?php echo $taxvat;?>" class="form-control">
       </div>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
public function getVatName()
         {
            $this->db->select('tax_price');
            $this->db->from('tbl_taxmaster');
            $this->db->where('tax_name',"VAT");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->row('tax_price');          
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**View**

<div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col col-md-4"><label class=" form-control-label">VAT</label></div>
            <?php foreach($taxvat as $row){ ?>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">


<input type="text" id="txtVat" name="txtVat" value="<?php echo $row->tax_price;?>" class="form-control">


                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?> 
                                </div>
**Controller**
public function displayBillingPage()
    {   

        $this->load->model('CrudModel');        
        $records['taxvat']=$this->CrudModel->getVatName();
        $this->load->view('generatebill',$records);
    }

**Model**
public function getVatName()
         {
            $this->db->select('tax_price');
            $this->db->from('tbl_taxmaster');
            $this->db->where('tax_name',"vat");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();          
         }
```